# is using TinyMCE a top choice for WYSIWYG editor on a webpage? What are good alternatives?

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg

is using TinyMCE a top choice for WYSIWYG editor on a webpage?  What are good alternatives?

some comparison seems to show that TinyMCE is one of the most compatible across browsers:

http://geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/WebEditors

Comment: I should mention that it's important to check your licensing whatever editor you end up using. Doing this in the beginning will save you a lot of headache down the line...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TinyMCE is a great choice.  I've used it in commercial offerings with good results.  I'm also looking at FCKEditor for a new project specifically because of the integrated file upload and rumors that it has better XSS protection.  Frankly, I'm not sure either one is sufficient to protect against XSS (you may have to supplement with something like http://htmlpurifier.org/ if that is a concern).

Comment: You definitely can't rely on them for XSS protection. All the user would have to do is disable javascript and post whatever HTML they want in the resulting textarea.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using FCKEditor with ASP.NET for years and have found it very easy to customize and configure.  It's very stable and the intergrated upload feature is a plus.  http://www.fckeditor.net/

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the best in my opinion:

http://www.openwebware.com/

Comment: As google chrome is my browser of choice i'm disappointed they have a notification on their demo site that "your browser is not supported", i'd rather a notification but for it to still attempt to render. Annoying that i can't use/test in chrome (maybe it's a feature that can be disabled in the code, but frustrating i have to go that far just for a demo!)

Comment: It does not even support Safari.

Answer (score 3):

[YUI Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)

Answer (score 2):

[Nicedit](http://nicedit.com/index.php) is useful for some simple text areas and it has a somewhat clean javascript api.

There is a list of other possible richtext boxes [here](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP or ASP.NET on the back end, take a look at [SPAW Editor](http://spaweditor.com).

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE and FCKeditor are the top two WYSIWYG editors in terms of popularity. They are both feature-rich and highly customizable. In my opinion TinyMCE is the easiest to use and maintain of the myriad different options, and still gets my vote after 4 years of usage. YUI is another nice choice worth evaluating, as are the others listed above. I've listed the demo pages for each below:

- [Tiny](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php#)
- [FCK (current site demo is broken, here's a cached site)](http://www.iterasi.net/openviewer.aspx?sqrlitid=shmodimkxu2x7trr6mvgvq)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/flickr_editor.html)
- [OpenWYSIWYG](http://www.openwebware.com/wysiwyg/demo.shtml)

I'm liking this Stack Overflow one as well though, +1 to the crew.
-EDIT- but then -1 because you treated me like a spammer with only 1 allowed hyperlink...

HTH
Jeff M.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE was the editor that we chose when we were making an internal staff website. The nice part about it was all the keyboard shortcuts (probably found in other editors) and that it was the same editor used inside of WordPress.

We were very happy with how the site turned out, and kept the editor. I would recommend TinyMCE for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the Stackoverflow site's solution?

you can find details in Stackoverflow's blog post here : [Potential Markup and Editing Choices](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/potential-markup-and-editing-choices/)

Answer (score 0):

As many have said here, FCKEditor is a good alternative. However, pay attention to the licensing models of the editors especially if you're planning on using them for a commercial, closed-source application.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/license.php

TinyMCE is just LGPL.

http://ckeditor.com/license

CKEditor (the most recent manifestation of FCK Editor) has a separate Closed Distribution License which may cost you some moulah...

I like the feature set and theme of FCKEditor/CKEditor better than TinyMCE but I often end up using TinyMCE due to it being a little simpler to handle in terms of licensing.

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned the [CuteEditor](http://cutesoft.net/example/general.aspx) yet. It's got a silly name, but it's actually quite nice to work with.  It's not free, but an enterprise license (which allows you to use it on any number of servers, dev workstations etc) is only 900 bucks or something ridiculously cheap.  I believe it's only availble for ASP.Net and classic ASP, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE and similar editors are not suitable for non-technical people who are likely to mess up the markup. Specially when said non-techy people copy formatted text from word into the RTE on the web page, thinking it's the most natural thing to do.

If you're audience is technical, something like markdown (as used here on SO) is more suitable.

If they're non-technical, let them use [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/) (WYM = what you mean), and provide some sort of a tutorial/explanation so they can use it.