# I am looking for a good html editor for my site

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver, tool-rec

I am building a php website and I am looking for an html editor where the user can type a message and press submit. The html editor should also include tags such as [img]..

Does anyone know where I can get one and put it into my Dreamweaver .. I use windows xp

Comment: Check this and choose the best answer:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953962/is-using-tinymce-a-top-choice-for-wysiwyg-editor-on-a-webpage-what-are-good-alte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.tinymce.com

I dont think you will find one to plugin to Dreamweaver and it doesn't matter what OS you are you.

Answer (score 2):

Go for [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: I've never heard of this, what advantages does it have over other WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE?

Comment: Its similiar to TinyMCE. Some CMS include it as part of their build. TinyMCE and ckeditor are similar except fckediotr does not rely on jquery.

Comment: I recommended ckeditor because i have used it personally and i dont find any problems with it , TinyMCE looks also good . Please specify more of your application requirements for CMS editor so that an exact one can be searched for

Comment: is there a tutorial on how to use tinymce

Answer (score 0):

Even though I use CKEditor, I like the fact that TinyMCE comes with a Image Manager. CKEditor also has a Image/File Manager but it's paid and does not have image crop functionality like TinyMCE.

Hmm, seems it's time to think about switching to TinyMCE ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can find this in DW. It's called a widget. And in fact, it's tinymce (it's been linked in this thread). Look under your INSERT menu for "Gadgets..." There are quite a few of them. One is exactly what you need.

VERY easy to install and you can customize any widget. You can even download the widgets code, if you want to make changes in the code.